# Python Dict Categories

Tags: python, dictionary, categories

I have a hangman game, and I am trying to use a dictionary for my categories for hangman so I don't have magic numbers, but whenever I try to create a dict like: 
`cat{animals:'animals', colors: 'colors'}` etc. It comes back with something like unhashable type: list.

Comment: Can you please post the exact thing you did? What you posted is not valid Python Syntax.

Answer (score 4):

`animals` or `colors` is probably a list.  I think you have the dictionary backwards (e.g. switch the order of the key/values so that you map a key string to a list value):

```
animals = ['cat','dog','liger']
d = {'animals':animals}
```

Comment: Thank you, mgilson, I hate it when I have such small mistakes.

Comment: @user2329136 -- happens to the best of us.